# What's the proper way of formatting writing from a character in a novel?

Tags: novel, formatting

I'm writing a story that constantly shows what the characters are writing.
I would like to know how to format that. Right now I'm doing it like this
(please ignore the grammar, it is a rough draft):

> The young women dressed as a nurse
> goes to the bar and orders a sandwich.
> After that, she check around looking
> for a sit. She finally decides to sit
> in one which is in front of the young
> man. He completely ignores that action
> and keeps writing. After some minutes,
> he finally stops to see what he has
> written.
>
> *Imaginary Interior Being Disorder. The patient loses contact with
> symbiosis and one-ness with nature and
> universe. Since he loses this
> connection, he doesn’t know what will
> happen if he dies, this makes the
> patient to be terrified of death. So
> he finally creates a invisible,
> eternal being to compensate that.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this question, since I think the same principle applies:
[What's a clear way to simulate web text in a story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/whats-a-clear-way-to-simulate-web-text-in-a-story)

Essentially, block indent the text.

I would also avoid the italics, if possible. Too much of it, and it becomes a pain for the reader to follow.

Answer (score 1):

For a sentence or a fragment of a sentence, quotation marks.  For a few paragraphs, block indent.  For substantial material, put it inline with a square-bracket explanation a few words in:

> He completely ignores that action and
>   keeps writing. After some minutes, he
>   finally stops to see what he has
>   written.
>
> Imaginary Interior Being Disorder **[it ran]** The
>   patient loses contact with symbiosis
>   and one-ness with nature and universe.
>   Since he loses this connection, he
>   doesn’t know what will happen if he
>   dies, this makes the patient to be
>   terrified of death.

And as Craig said, be wary of italics.  They quickly become tiresome to read.